# python-purple fails with "CRITICAL **: purple_ssl_connect_with_ssl_cn: assertion 'purple_ssl_is_supported()'"

Tags: ssl, pidgin, finch, libpurple

I'm using `python-purple` to build own chat application with `lipburple`. When I use Facebook or Hangouts plugin, which require SSL connection, I get the error:

`** (process:6574): CRITICAL **: purple_ssl_connect_with_ssl_cn: assertion 'purple_ssl_is_supported()' failed`

The same is with `node-purple` bindings for `libpurple`.

`libpurple` is installed with

`sudo apt-get install pidgin-dev`

`finch` works fine - connects to all SSL services as it should do, but when I start `nullclient.py` with Facebook acount, I get the error shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

**`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libpurple.so`**`python nullclient.py`